# Framework-agnostic reactivity?

Tags: javascript

I've made some functionality in my Vue app and thought to make it a separate packet, which maybe i'll publish. At the moment this code uses ref() in some places to reach reactivity - output function is returning dynamically changing data. And first question i get to is how to make this reactivity completely framework independent. Is it possible?
Example for clear understanding:

```js
    class someWorker {
        private results
        constructor() {
           this.results = ref([])
        }
        ...
        updateResults() {
          //some work...
          this.results.value.concat(someArray)
        }

        getResults() { //this function must return reactive
            return this.results.value
        }
    }
```

Comment: Typically by emitting events